# Bundling a JRE with a launch4j application in gradle

Tags: java, gradle, launch4j

### Background

I'm using the edu.sc.seis.launch4j plugin to build distributable applications using a gradle build script. I'm trying to produce these with a bundled JRE.

This is the gradle script

```
plugins {
    id 'org.jetbrains.intellij' version '0.3.7'
    id 'java'
    id 'edu.sc.seis.launch4j' version '2.4.4'
}

group 'worldbuilders'
version '0.4.4-SNAPSHOT'

apply plugin: 'application'

sourceCompatibility = 1.8

repositories {
    jcenter()
    mavenCentral()
}

mainClassName = 'hello.HelloWorld'

dependencies {
    testCompile group: 'junit', name: 'junit', version: '4.12'
}

intellij {
    version '2017.3.5'
}

launch4j {
    bundledJrePath = "jre" //my jre to use is in the projectRoot/jre folder but I think that's not what this parameter is for anyway
    mainClassName = 'hello.HelloWorld'
    bundledJre64Bit = true
    //icon = "${projectDir}/icons/myApp.ico"
}
```

Frustratingly this creates an application that runs (exe created by the gradle task createExe) but clearly doesn't have a JRE bundled in/next to it, presumably because it runs because it falls back to using the system jre, which makes testing things difficult. If I put a deliberately corrupted jre at /jre/ it still seems to run, which is even more confusing

### Question

How can i bundle a JRE with my exe distributable created using the gradle-launch4j plugin? (And that is actually used by the exe rather than using the system jre)

### Additional information

The debug XML created by the plugin (that is consumed by launch4j):

Created with the command `gradle createExe -Pl4j-debug`

```
<?xml version='1.0' encoding='UTF-8'?>
<launch4jConfig>
  <dontWrapJar>false</dontWrapJar>
  <headerType>gui</headerType>
  <jar>lib/onemillionworlds-0.4.4-SNAPSHOT.jar</jar>
  <outfile>onemillionworlds.exe</outfile>
  <errTitle></errTitle>
  <cmdLine></cmdLine>
  <chdir>.</chdir>
  <priority>normal</priority>
  <downloadUrl>http://java.com/download</downloadUrl>
  <supportUrl></supportUrl>
  <stayAlive>false</stayAlive>
  <restartOnCrash>false</restartOnCrash>
  <manifest></manifest>
  <icon></icon>
  <classPath>
    <mainClass>hello.HelloWorld</mainClass>
    <cp>lib\onemillionworlds-0.4.4-SNAPSHOT.jar</cp>
    <cp>lib\tools.jar</cp>
    <cp>lib\jme3-lwjgl-3.2.0-stable.jar</cp>
    <cp>lib\jme3-desktop-3.2.0-stable.jar</cp>
    <cp>lib\jme3-core-3.2.0-stable.jar</cp>
    <cp>lib\lwjgl-2.9.3.jar</cp>
    <cp>lib\lwjgl-platform-2.9.3-natives-windows.jar</cp>
    <cp>lib\lwjgl-platform-2.9.3-natives-linux.jar</cp>
    <cp>lib\lwjgl-platform-2.9.3-natives-osx.jar</cp>
    <cp>lib\jinput-2.0.5.jar</cp>
    <cp>lib\jutils-1.0.0.jar</cp>
    <cp>lib\jinput-platform-2.0.5-natives-linux.jar</cp>
    <cp>lib\jinput-platform-2.0.5-natives-windows.jar</cp>
    <cp>lib\jinput-platform-2.0.5-natives-osx.jar</cp>
  </classPath>
  <jre>
    <path>jre</path>
    <bundledJre64Bit>true</bundledJre64Bit>
    <bundledJreAsFallback>false</bundledJreAsFallback>
    <minVersion>1.8.0</minVersion>
    <maxVersion></maxVersion>
    <jdkPreference>jdkOnly</jdkPreference>
    <runtimeBits>64/32</runtimeBits>
  </jre>
  <versionInfo>
    <fileVersion>0.0.0.1</fileVersion>
    <txtFileVersion>unspecified</txtFileVersion>
    <fileDescription>onemillionworlds</fileDescription>
    <copyright>unknown</copyright>
    <productVersion>0.0.0.1</productVersion>
    <txtProductVersion>unspecified</txtProductVersion>
    <productName>onemillionworlds</productName>
    <companyName></companyName>
    <internalName>onemillionworlds</internalName>
    <originalFilename>onemillionworlds.exe</originalFilename>
    <trademarks></trademarks>
    <language>ENGLISH_US</language>
  </versionInfo>
</launch4jConfig>
```

Comment: is `launch4j.xml`generated ?

Comment: @toYonos I believe the plugin hides that away but I think I can make it produce it. I'll have a look

Comment: I did a try and no xml file generated. But the plugin has a `xmlFileName` property and in the doc you can find assertions like *To avoid replacing the resulting xml file or executable on each invocation[...]*

Comment: @ToYonos I've got it to generate the intermediate xml file and added it to the question

Comment: The `jre` dir is not packaged by Gradle, did you manually add it when you tried to make it work ? (It does not explain why there is no xml file in the end though)

Comment: @ToYonos I think it's supposed to remove the xml file automatically unless you ask it not to (which is what i did to get the quoted xml). I have tried putting the jre there manually. However it seems to work without it (making me think it's still trying to use the system Jre). I tried corrupting the jre and it still worked.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

## Pragmatic answer

Looking at this with 2 years distance I realise my question was effectively "I want Launch4J to behave exactly like a bat file". For the linux release I used the linux equivalent of a bat, an sh file, and in retrospect I should have done the same for the windows release.

## Literal answer

The bundledJrePath config for launch4j is telling launch4j where to find the JRE, not where to put it, you must seperately put it there. And if launch4j can't find it it will use the installed JRE (or download one).

My relevant Gradle config ended up like this

```
launch4j { //used for windows
    mainClassName = 'mygame.Main'
    bundledJrePath = 'jre'
    bundledJre64Bit = true
    jreMinVersion = '11'
}

task packageExecutableDistribution(type: Zip) {
    archiveName = "oneMillionWorlds.zip"
    destinationDir = file("$buildDir/distExecutable")

    from "$buildDir/launch4j"
}

task addJreToDistributable(type: Copy) {
    from zipTree("resources/desktop-deployment/OpenJDK11U-jre_x64_windows_hotspot_11.0.4_11.zip")
    destinationDir = file("$buildDir/launch4j")
}

packageExecutableDistribution.dependsOn createExe
packageExecutableDistribution.dependsOn addJreToDistributable
```

And my folder structure ended up like this

[image]

## Where to find JREs

As its become a little hard to find JREs these days, you can find adoptium builds of JREs at https://adoptium.net/en-GB/temurin/releases/ or if you want to be able to programmatically grab JREs you can find links to them in json format from `https://api.adoptium.net/v3/assets/feature_releases/[DESIRED_VERSION]/ga?image_type=jre`, so for example [https://api.adoptium.net/v3/assets/feature_releases/19/ga?image_type=jre](https://api.adoptium.net/v3/assets/feature_releases/11/ga?image_type=jre)

Alternatively you can start with the JDK and use JLink to produce a minimal JRE for your use case

Comment: Good, but would it be possible to include the jre and lib folders within the jar that is inside the exe? Would look neater. And, what do you use for MacOs and Linux, if any?

Comment: @carl bundling a jre means its OS specific. So for linux you'd need a sh file and a linux specific JRE if going for the pragmatic answer. Launch4j is just for windows so wouldn't apply to the other OSs

Comment: my main issue here is i cant find an jre19 for openjdk19 ...

Comment: @Mosch Yeah, it is a bit of a pain to find these days (I blame Oracle). I've added links to the adoptium builds of the JREs (which are the ones you can use without a painful license)